# How to create a query to get previous dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a date and trying to get previous 5 months end date as below:

```
DECLARE @date Date =  '2020-04-30'

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @date)-1, -1)
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -2, @date)-1, -1)
---
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -5, @date)-1, -1)
```

Is there a way to get all previous dates in a single query if we pass previous number of months in a variable in above case it is 5 in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Why not just add a comma after every dateadd statement, so you get multiple columns (and thus all in 1 statement/query)?

Comment: All the statements return `2020-03-31 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: I just realised that after i wrote the answer, @Zhorov . Not actually sure what the OP *is* after, but will be easy enough to adjust once we do know.

Comment: @Larnu . say if we want previous month  end dates , we'll have a variable  which will hold number months in this case 5 and  we get dates based on that number.

Comment: @AlexT82 because number of months can vary .in this case it is 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have parameter and generate previous months last day as given below for SQL Server 2008.

```sql
-- OLD Version
DECLARE @dt DATE
SET @dt = GETDATE()
DECLARE @n INT = 3 --number of previous months
;WITH CTE_previousMonths AS
(
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dt),0)) AS DATE)as LastDayOfMonth, 1 AS lvl
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,LastDayOfMonth),0)) AS DATE)as LastDayOfMonth, lvl+1 AS lvl
FROM CTE_previousMonths WHERE lvl < @n
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_previousMonths
```

```
+----------------+-----+
| LastDayOfMonth | lvl |
+----------------+-----+
| 2020-04-30     |   1 |
| 2020-03-31     |   2 |
| 2020-02-29     |   3 |
+----------------+-----+
```

Comment: I am getting this error if number of month is huge say 1000: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: go for option (maxrecursion 1000) to inrease the recursion.

Comment: ok,where we need to do a change if we need month start date?

Comment: I would suggest you to ask it as a separate question. changing question will lead to confusion for future persons looking for answer.

Comment: This is why I recommended a Tally, @Harsh , they don't suffer the recursion error as they aren't recursive, and thus much faster.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you mean this?

```
DECLARE @date date =  '2020-04-30';

SELECT EOMONTH(@date, T.I)
FROM (VALUES(-1),(-2),(-3),(-4),(-5))T(I)
ORDER BY T.I DESC;
```

If you want a much larger range, then you can create the tally on the fly:

```
DECLARE @date date =  '2020-04-30',
        @Months int = 500; --

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Months) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1,  N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT EOMONTH(@Date, T.I * -1)
FROM Tally T;
```

---

It appears the OP is using an unsupported version of SQL Server and omitted to tell us this. They can use the below in SQL Server 2008 (I don't recall if it works in 2005):

```
DECLARE @date date =  '2020-04-30';

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+T.I,0))
FROM (VALUES(0),(-1),(-2),(-3),(-4))T(I)
ORDER BY T.I DESC;
```

For larger ranges, this will work in 2008, but *will not* work in 2005 or prior. But if you are using either of these version, it's past time you get the upgrade done (especially for SQL Server 2005):

```
DECLARE @date date =  '2020-04-30',
        @Months int = 500;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Months) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1,  N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)-T.I,0))
FROM Tally T;
```

Comment: EOMONTH is not a built in function in my case :( also can we provide a variable in VALUES?

Comment: `EOMONTH` is available in every **supported** version of SQL Server, @Harsh . If you are using an unsupported version, you should be letting the users know, as we will make the assumption that you otherwise have access to either the oldest supported version, or the latest and greatest. What version of SQL Server are you actually using?

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: Then, like I said, you should really be telling us you're using unsupported software, @Harsh . SQL Server 2008 has been unsupported for almost an entire year now.

Answer (score 1):

use `EOMONTH()` to get the end of month date

```
DECLARE @date Date =  '2020-04-30'
SELECT  EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @date)),
        EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @date)),
        EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @date)),
        EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, @date)),
        EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -5, @date))
```

You wanted it in column or row wise ?

```
SELECT  EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @date)) UNION ALL
SELECT  EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @date)) UNION ALL
SELECT  EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @date)) UNION ALL
SELECT  EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, @date)) UNION ALL
SELECT  EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -5, @date))
```

Comment: He is having SQL Server 2008. EOMONTH is supported from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Comment: the `SQL Server 2008` requirement was not in the question initially

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I was late to join the party :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MonthsBack int     =   5                           -- Amount of Months you want to go back
DECLARE @TargetDate date    =  '2020-04-30'                 -- Date where we start to go back

WHILE   @MonthsBack > 0                                     -- Loop until no more months to go back
    BEGIN                                   
        SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, -1*@MonthsBack, @TargetDate) --  Function to add any datepart to a date.
                                                            --  If the number of parts is negative, it will substarct instead.
                                                            --  In our case we want to add Months, so we pick that interval.
                                                            --  Since we really want to substract (go back), we multiply the amount of months by -1
        SET @MonthsBack = @MonthsBack - 1                   --  Now, decrease the loop variable, same we use to substract months.
    END
;
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?